# How do I get Android SDK for Morpho 1300 fingerprint scanner?

Tags: biometrics

I tried looking at their website. But got no clues. How can I get Android SDK and also any sample server code if possible that helps me in creating resgistration of fingerprint and authentication? That will be bonus.
TIA

Comment: Did u find any success? I am looking for similar thing

Comment: @Godwin did you find any success?

Comment: Hi guys, Have you found any solution.I am also stuck with Morpho Android SDK.Please help me on this.